# How to get stationery back in Apple Mail on macOS Mojave?

Tags: mail.app, beta-seed-program, mojave

According to [this](https://www.macstories.net/news/macos-mojave-a-roundup-of-all-the-little-things/) article, Apple has removed the stationery from Apple Mail.

> **Apple Mail Stationery Removed.** According to the release notes for the
>   macOS Mojave beta, Stationery, the HTML email feature that allowed
>   users to choose from pre-built email templates, has been removed from
>   the app.

I have installed the first beta of macOS Mojave and it appears that this is unfortunately true.  Is there anyway to regain this functionality of Apple Mail and add stationery to Apple Mail v12.0?

Comment: 10k views yet -1???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You must have a copy of the following files from a computer running High Sierra (10.13) or lower** In this example I used files from Sierra (10.12)

- `/Applications/Mail/Contents/Resources/ComposeWindow.toolbar`
- `/Library/Application Support/Apple/Mail`

If you would like the stationery in the original mail application then skip step 1, disable **SIP**, and continue with the original application, **SIP** can be reenabled after. **Make copies of everything**. Instead of "replace" add a `.orig` to the file extension.

1. Duplicate the Mail Application
2. Right click on the new Mail Application and go to `/Contents/Resources/`
3. Replace the `ComposeWindow.toolbar` with the `ComposeWindow.toolbar` from the copied files
4. Go to Finder>Go To Folder>`/Library/Application Support/Apple/`
5. Copy the `Mail` folder from the copied files to this folder
6. Open the Mail application and compose a new email
7. Right Click on the Toolbar and select `Customize Toolbar`
8. Drag the icon labeled `Show Stationery` to your toolbar and hit done
9. Click the `Show Stationery` button in your toolbar

**Note:**  The toolbar item **DOES** work with dark mode but the Stationery Panel **does not**.

---

**macOS Sierra (10.12) Files are available on Github** → https://github.com/jbis9051/StationeryMailFiles

Comment: That would be great, but unfortunately folks have upgraded to Mojave already and 99% of them have no access to High Sierra or Sierra to be able to do this, so therefore they are stuck with no solution. I encourage customer's to continue to submit feedback at http://www.apple.com/feedback using macOS > Mail to get this to the developers. I wish you all the best.

Comment: @Larry I will add download link soon.

Comment: Because I didn't have a computer I used a time machine backup from before I upgraded to OS 14 and restored the 2 files mentioned above to my desktop. Then just followed directions in the wonderful instructions below. Worked beautifully!

Comment: @Larry I added the files for download. Sorry about the delay. I forgot.

Comment: I tried this on Monterey using files from a Time Machine backup of the machine from before upgrading. I'm not entirely sure, but I believe the old OS was Mavericks, Yosemite or El Capitan. It did not work - what happened was that the toolbar in a new message came up with no icons, and the new button, labelled "ToolbarShowStationary" is grey and un-clickable.